# Data.table alternative to pmap and reduce?

Tags: r

Hoping to get this process faster if possible. I have two very large dataframes (abbreviated examples provided below).

df1 is a shorter dataframe where each row represents a patient hospitalisation. eid is each hopsitalisation, pid is a patient id and doa is a date integer

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

eid <- seq(1,4,1)
pid <- c(rep(111,2),rep(222,1),333)
doa <- as.numeric(c(1500,1100,600,200))
df1 <- as_tibble(cbind(eid,pid,doa))
```

df2 is a generally a longer dataframe where each row represents a specific drug prescription. pid is a patient id that matches the same pid in df1. drug is the type of drug prescribed. dop is the date prescribed as an integer.

```
pid <- c(rep(111,2),rep(222,3))
drug <- c('a','a','b','c','a')
dop <- as.numeric(c(550,900,950,1000,500))
df2 <- as_tibble(cbind(pid,drug,dop))
```

Effectively I want a column for each drug appended to  df1. I have shown the example for drug 'a' as below:

```
df2 <- df2 %>% 
filter(drug=='a')

drug <- pmap(list(df1$pid,df1$doa),
function (x,y)
list(case_when(
#id match
df2$pid==x &  y-as.numeric(df2$dop) < 365 &y-as.numeric(df2$dop) > 0 ~1,
#id match and drug discharge <365 days
T ~ 0)
))

drug

dat <- data.table(matrix(unlist(drug),nrow=dim(df1)[1],byrow = T))

fun1 <- function (x) ifelse(x==1,T,F)

dat <- dat[,drug_a:=Reduce('|',lapply(.SD, fun1)), .SDcols = 1:3]
```

The final result i want is a data frame to look like

```
df1 <- cbind(df1,dat[,'drug_a'])
```

But for drug_a, drug_b, drug_c etc

df1 has 400,000 rows but df2 has 200 million rows

Is there a more faster and efficient process than what i have described above?

Thanks

Comment: I think I'm still confused about what you're trying to achieve. For each hospitalisation, you want to add a logical column for each drug that denotes what?

Comment: if at the hospitalisation that drug was prescribed less than 365 days ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could try this. It's not in `data.table`, but you're basically just trying to avoid loops. This kind of stuff is hard to benchmark without the original data because not every function scales the same, but I would expect this to be a lot faster and cleaner than your current method and extends to as many drugs as you need.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(
  eid = seq(1, 4, 1),
  pid = c(rep(111, 2), rep(222, 1), 333),
  doa = as.numeric(c(1500, 1100, 600, 200))
)
df2 <- tibble(
  pid = c(rep(111, 2), rep(222, 3)),
  drug = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "a"),
  dop = as.numeric(c(550, 900, 950, 1000, 500))
)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "pid") %>% # one row per patient-hospitaliation-drug-prescription
  mutate(days_since_prescription = doa - dop) %>%
  group_by(eid, pid, drug) %>%
  summarise(within_365 = any(days_since_prescription < 365 & days_since_prescription > 0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% # now one row per patient-hospitalisation-drug
  spread(drug, within_365, sep = "_") %>% # now one row per patient-hospitalisation
  select(-drug_NA) %>% # cleanup tasks
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("drug")), replace_na, replace = FALSE) # skip this if you want to preserve knowing whether a prescription took place
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>     eid   pid drug_a drug_b drug_c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl> 
#> 1     1   111 FALSE  FALSE  FALSE 
#> 2     2   111 TRUE   FALSE  FALSE 
#> 3     3   222 TRUE   FALSE  FALSE 
#> 4     4   333 FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Created on 2018-09-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Awesome...this will be a factor fold faster - thank you